# Ubuntu (14.04) small screen on VMware (4.2.12)

Tags: 14.04, screen, vmware, xrandr

I am getting small screen of Ubuntu after installation on VMware. I have tried installation twice. On trying to install Guest addition it gives error -

"the headers of current running kernel were not found"

on checking with **xrandr** it gives only 640x480 as output

xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 640 x 480, maximum 640 x 480
default connected primary 640x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   640x480        73.0*

I have also increased **video memory** in VM to 40 MB

Comment: The video memory won't help much - you do need the headers though.  Try  "sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`"

Answer (score 0):

The video memory won't help much - you do need the headers though.  Try

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

This will install the headers for the version of Ubuntu that you are running, and ensure that the build tools are available.