# Screen resolution problems

Tags: drivers, display, screen

I've been fixing some old laptops for donations to poor students and been installing Ubuntu in all of them because they are very obsolete (stuff from 2010 and behind). Recently, I got two laptops that I can't seem to fix the screen resolution. I tried installing Ubuntu 18.04.05, 18.04 and now they are running on 16.04 32-bit.

When I plug in the bootable USB to install the OS, the screen resolution is great and works fine, but once the installation is finished and I reboot it to finish the configuration before the donation, the screen resolution is set to 640x480 (4:3).

Running xrandr gives back the same result for both laptops:

```
xradr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 640 x 480, maximum 640 x 480
default connected primary 640x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm
    640x480     73.00*
```

On settings it shows "Unknown screen". If I connect a second screen and reboot it with Ubuntu running, it won't do anything, but if I reboot the system with the second screen connected, it will load with 1280x760 resolution on both the second screen (VGA interface) and on the laptop screen. Then I can disconnect the second screen and keep the 1280x760 resolution, but if I reboot again without the second screen connected, it will be back to same results as above.

Running xrandr while still with 1280x760 will show the same results as above, but with 1280x760 in the places of 640x480, but everything else is the same.

Tried to `sudo nano grub` to check for `nomodeset`, which were not there, but once I put it in, it helped solve the flashing dots on screen that was another problem I was having.

[This suggested question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/518222/ubuntu-14-04-small-screen-on-vmware-4-2-12) mentioned the command `sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-uname -r` which returned with `E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?`

[This other suggested question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227876/how-to-set-custom-resolution-using-xrandr-when-the-resolution-is-not-available-i) mentioned (adapted) using `cvt 1280 760 60` and running `xrandr --addmode` with the string result, which ran good, but I can't set the new mode on settings (returns an error saying the maximum is 640x480). Using the command `xrandr --output default --mode "1280x780_60.00"`returns `Configure crtc 0 failed`.

One of the laptops is a Intel Core2Duo T6600, 4GB RAM, the other one is T5300, 1GB RAM. Graphics appears as llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0, 128 bits) on both, none of them have a dedicated graphics card.

So... any ideas? :)

--- EDIT ---
Adding more information as requested:

**lspci:**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 671MX
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] AGP Port (virtual PCI-to-PCI bridge)
00:02.0 ISA bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] SiS968 [MuTIOL Media IO] (rev 01)
00:02.5 IDE interface: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 5513 IDE Controller (rev 01)
00:03.0 USB controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 1.1 Controller (rev 0f)
00:03.1 USB controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 1.1 Controller (rev 0f)
00:03.3 USB controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] USB 2.0 Controller
00:04.0 Ethernet controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 191 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter (rev 02)
00:05.0 IDE interface: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] SATA Controller / IDE mode (rev 03)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] PCI-to-PCI bridge
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] PCI-to-PCI bridge
00:0f.0 Audio device: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] Azalia Audio Controller
00:1f.0 PCI bridge: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] PCI-to-PCI bridge
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 771/671 PCIE VGA Display Adapter (rev 10)
03:00.0 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. SD/MMC Host Controller
03:00.2 SD Host controller: JMicron Technology Corp. Standard SD Host Controller
03:00.3 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. MS Host Controller
```

**xrandr**
[image: xrandr with default screen]

**>>> second screen connected <<<**
[image: This is the result of both commands with second screen connected]

**xrandr set mode**
[image: Trying to set mode on xrandr WITHOUT second screen connected]

Comment: The `xrandr --output default --mode "1280x780_60.00"` command has a typo. Not sure if it's accidental or not, but `780` should be looked at. Can you update your question to include the full output of both `lspci` and `xrandr`? This might contain some helpful info to solve the problem.

Comment: @Matigo done. Added information about the xrandr set mode as well. Tried to change language to EN but I couldn't select the option, so a few things are shown in PT-BR